# Is there a way to pass different vertical lines to each subplot when using pandas histogram with "by=somevar"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, histogram

I'm making histograms using pandas and I find this approach convenient.

For example if I do:

df['plotvar'].hist(by='Zone')

I get

[image: Histograms]
But now I want to add the 95%CI on each of these subgroups, and of course the intervals are different for each group. I could do it just using plt.axvline in matplotlib, but not sure how to do it when I've made the original plots using pandas. TIA for any inputs/suggestions.

edit: I shoudl add that I already know what the 95%CI values are. This is just a plotting question (how to apply the axvline to each of these subplots). Thx.

Comment: Pandas is just using matplotlib, you should be able to mix "pandas" plotting commands with matplotlib ones without any problems.

Comment: I get that, but when I do it using pandas, I'm not sure how to access each subplot. If I did it all in matplotlib, I'd just define each subplot on the way in (i.e., 111, or whatever) and then put the axvline on each chart as it's made. But when I make them this way with pandas (which does have certain advantages for what I'm trying to do) then I don't know how to get in there and add the axvline to each plot after they have been created this way. It woudl be ideal if pandas would let me broactast a list or array axvline x values onto the group, or some such. Not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.hist()` with `by=` returns the array of matplotlib Axes, so you could grab that and then iterate over it.

For similar functionality that speaks pandas but has more flexible features you could use the [FacetGrid](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/many_facets.html) object from [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn).