# Pandas plot function returns np.array - how to get it to return AxesSubplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am using the pandas plotting function for histogram subplots.

```
    df.plot.hist(subplots = True)
```

I would like to add a vertical line to each of the plots. I know you can do this in matplotlib plot using

```
    plt.axvlines
```

But how do I access the individual subplots generated by pandas? 
I looked  at :[Is there a way to pass different vertical lines to each subplot when using pandas histogram with "by=somevar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917580/is-there-a-way-to-pass-different-vertical-lines-to-each-subplot-when-using-panda) 
But can someone please give me an actual example of how to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.hist()` returns a list of `Axes` object. You just have to iterate over each axis and add you vertical line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,5)))
axs = df.plot.hist(subplots = True)
for ax in axs:
    ax.axvline(0.5)
```

Comment: I get this error with your solution: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'axvline'

Comment: I see here - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html - that df.plot.hist generates Axes object OR a numpy array. Which is clearly what is giving me an error. Any idea get a list of Axes instead?

Comment: You'll have to provide a sample DataFrame. In my tests, I've never been able to return any thing else but either 1 `Axes` object, or a list of `Axes`. Have you tried using `DataFrame.hist()` instead of `DataFrame.plot.hist()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue you mentioned:

```
ax = daily_returns.hist(bins=20)  # changing no. of bins to 20
print(ax)
```

And by printing the result I got:

```
[[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000021F1BEBEF28>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000021F1C0F8208>]]
```

So in my case I woulnd need to do something like ax[0][0] and ax[0][1] to get to the axes